# OAuth2.createService does exceed storage capacity in PropertiesServices?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I’m using the statement

```
myService = OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:' + USER_EMAIL);
```

in a Google Script.

This has worked well just up to a few days ago, but now the service is not created anymore:  `myService.hasAccess()`  returns `false`.

Executing the code, I obtain the following error message:

> “You have exceeded the property storage quota. Please remove some properties and try again.”

Actually the property storage is empty. I added also the statement

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(). proprietaScript.deleteAllProperties();
```

Before creating the service.
Does anybody have an idea to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has the same problem, I found the following solution.
I substituted the statements

```
return OAuth2.createService(…)
   .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
```

with

```
return OAuth2.createService(…)
   .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
```

and I added the statement

```
.setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
```

in order to not exhaust the PropertiesService quotas.
You can find the complete use of OAuth2 for Apps Script in [this link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2).